# Example of graph $G=(V,E)$ without a perfect matching where $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for every $S\subset V$

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I have been asked to find a graph $G=(V,E)$ **without** a perfect matching where $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for every $S\subset V$. This to show that Halls marriage theorem does not hold for non-biparite graphs but I cannot really find one graph that fulfills this.

I guess this is quite trivial but I have a hard time to really understand how to find graphs such that $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for every $S\subset V$ without perfect matchings, does anyone have any idea about such graph?

Later on I have seen the following link, but I wonder if there is a less complicated graph?

[an example for an arbitrary graph $G$ with even vertices which $\forall S \in V(G) , |N(S)|\geq |S| $ but there is no complete matching .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075727/an-example-for-an-arbitrary-graph-g-with-even-vertices-which-forall-s-in-v)

Comment: How about $K_3$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have any thought about what I wrote as a comment under Mike's answer?

Comment: In general, I have no idea, I'm no expert on graph algorithms. My answer to the question you linked to had to be a little more complicated, because that question specified an even number of vertices, making the question slightly less trivial. That $10$-vertex example still has enough symmetry that it's not so hard to check the condition $|N(S)|\ge|S|$. I will edit my answer to that question to show that. By the way, does your notation $G=(E,V)$ mean a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$? I don't believe I've ever seen it written that way before, it's usually written $G=(V,E)$.

Comment: Yeah I guess these "school book" questions relies a lot on using symmetry to find that $|N(S)|\geq |S|$.

And yes, I should have used $(V,E)$ instead of $(E,V)$, I think it just slipped my mind and I simply wrote it in alphabetical order. Now looking at $(E,V)$ it looks quite odd. I will edit it.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to the linked question to include a detailed verification of $|N(S)|\ge|S|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @bof beat me to it, but $K_3$ will do. In fact, $K_{2k+1}$ for any positive integer $k$ will do as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I can see that $K_3$ has no perfect matching. I have a question about how to check that $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for a general graph. In the case of $K_3$ I guess you only need to check the case when $S$ is zero, one, two and three nodes because of the symmetry. Is there a good way to check $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for bigger more complicated graph (without the symmetry complete graphs has), like the one linked to in the original post?